# Can I pipe part of my bash scripts output to a file? Can I pipe to a file and stdout?

Tags: bash, ksh, sh

I am pretty sure I've seen this done before, but I can't seem to find it by google.

```
for file in $mydir/*
do
    #redirect the rest to $myotherdir/$file.output.
    echo this should go to the $myotherdir/$file.output.
done
```

It would also be great if I could use `tee` instead of a redirect, so that it goes to that file and stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any of at least three techniques.  One is illustrated by [dtmilano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236465/dtmilano)'s answer, using a full sub-shell and parentheses, but be careful about clobbering previous output:

```
outfile=/$myotherdir/$file.output

for file in $mydir/*
do
    (
    ...commands...
    ) >> $outfile
    ...other commands with output going elsewhere...
done
```

Or you can use braces to group the I/O redirection without starting a sub-shell:

```
outfile=/$myotherdir/$file.output

for file in $mydir/*
do
    {
    ...commands...
    } >> $outfile
    ...other commands with output going elsewhere...
done
```

Or you can sometimes use `exec`:

```
exec 1>&3    # Preserve original standard output as fd 3
outfile=/$myotherdir/$file.output

for file in $mydir/*
do
    exec 1>>$outfile
    ...standard output
    exec 1>&3
    ...other commands with output going to original stdout...
done
```

I'd normally use the `{ ... }` notation, but it is cranky in a 1-line scenario; the `}` must appear where a command could start:

```
{ ls; date; } >/tmp/x37
```

The second semicolon is needed there.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
for file in $mydir/*
do
   (
     commands
     ...
   ) > /$myotherdir/$file.output
   echo this should go to the $file > $file
done
```

Comment: Any idea what this technique is called? Also, the echo should be amongst the commands. There is no reason to do two redirects.

Comment: Nevermind, my question was confusing.. thats why you did that.

Comment: @Jonathan may have been referring to the line `echo this should go to the $file > $file` -- this truncates $file before the shell executes the echo command.

Comment: OK - my bad.  I'll remove my comment(s).